# How to get the errno from an IOError in haskell?

Tags: haskell, io, ghc, errno

I'm on the haskell platform, GHC 6.12.1 as apt-get installed on Debian Squeeze.  How can I get the underlying errno out of an IOError, given that I need it on a different thread to where it was originally raised?

The reason I need this is because I'm implementing a network protocol which exposes the actual errno value on the wire.  Do I need to reconstruct it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`errno` is [thread-local](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.1/Foreign-C-Error.html#v%3agetErrno) in GHC. You'll need to trap the errno in one thread; then send the value down a `Chan` or other communication abstraction to your listening thread.

The [value itself](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/browser/includes/rts/storage/TSO.h?rev=9d26519c20194abc3832578a55fbe31327519eeb#L130) is stored in [thread TSO structure](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/parallel/multicore-ghc.pdf#4.1).

Comment: I'm getting an IOError out of an IO.try call then punting the IOError down a TChan. Do you mean that I either need to replace the IO.try with a different mechanism, or that I should look up the errno once I've got the IOError immediately after the IO.try?

Comment: You should grab errno at the same time as you catch the exception, since it may get cleared otherwise.