# `getErrno` and threads

Tags: multithreading, haskell, ghc, errno

The documentation for [`getErrno`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Foreign-C-Error.html#v:getErrno) reads:

> Get the current value of errno in the current thread.

It is unclear to me whether this means the current *OS* thread. In particular, does the (threaded) runtime fetch and stash away `errno` whenever a Haskell thread is migrated from one OS thread to another?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10497765/how-to-get-the-errno-from-an-ioerror-in-haskell) seems related, but it is unclear to me whether what is said there pertains to OS or Haskell threads.

Comment: If you [look at the source](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/src/Foreign-C-Error.html#getErrno), there's a comment "We must call a C function to get the value of errno in general.  On threaded systems, errno is hidden behind a C macro so that each OS thread gets its own copy." which indicates that it means OS thread.

Comment: Yeah, each OS thread has its own `errno` in general from what I understand, but what I wonder is: Does GHC's threaded runtime ensure that this is brought along whenever a Haskell thread is migrated from one OS thread to another?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For recent versions of GHC at least, the runtime saves `errno` in the Thread Storage Object (`TSO`) and takes care of managing it when it migrates a runtime thread to another OS thread. That means it should be safe to rely on `errno` in both unbound (`forkIO`) and bound (`forkOS`) threads. Here's a test for Linux:

`err.hs`

```
import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Exception
import Foreign.C

foreign import ccall safe get_ostid :: IO CUInt
foreign import ccall safe sleep :: CUInt -> IO CUInt
foreign import ccall unsafe get_errno :: IO CInt
foreign import ccall unsafe set_errno :: CInt -> IO ()

forkIO' f = do
  done <- newEmptyMVar
  forkIO (f `finally` putMVar done ())
  return (takeMVar done)

prefix = do
  id <- get_ostid
  return $ show id ++ ": "

main = do
  wait <- forkIO' $ do -- spawn a lightweight thread
    errno <- get_errno
    (putStr =<< prefix) >> putStrLn ("outer errno is " ++ show errno)
    (putStr =<< prefix) >> putStrLn "Setting outer errno to 3"
    set_errno 3
    wait' <- forkIO' $ do -- spawn another lightweight thread
      errno <- get_errno
      (putStr =<< prefix) >> putStrLn ("inner errno is " ++ show errno)
      (putStr =<< prefix) >> putStrLn "Setting inner errno to 2"
      set_errno 2
      sleep 2 -- force this lightweight thread to tie up the OS thread
      errno <- get_errno
      (putStr =<< prefix) >> putStrLn ("inner errno is " ++ show errno)
    threadDelay 1000000 -- wait a second
    -- By now, we should be in another OS thread.
    errno <- get_errno
    (putStr =<< prefix) >> putStrLn ("outer errno is " ++ show errno)
    wait'
  wait
```

`err.c`

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int get_errno(void) { return errno; }
void set_errno(int e) { errno = e; }

unsigned get_ostid(void) {
  return syscall(SYS_gettid);
}
```

Compile with:

```
ghc -o err -threaded err.hs err.c
```

And the result should look something like:

```
12282: outer errno is 0
12282: Setting outer errno to 3
12282: inner errno is 0
12282: Setting inner errno to 2
12283: outer errno is 3
12282: inner errno is 2
```

The OS thread IDs are printed at the beginning of each line. Note that the `errno` of `3` was migrated to the second OS thread (`12283`).